# Portable c++ boost::iterprocess::mutex, an another try

Tags: c++, synchronization, multiprocess, boost-mutex, robust

I was looking for long time around to have portable robust solution for multiprocessing synchronization. Who touche this things know that good solution are boost::iterprocess named
sync objects. But ....
When your process have named_mutex locked and your process die (there are many normal situations when process die, not just bug or others.) In that case named_mutex will remain in locked state. There were attempt to make robust_mutex in boost code done by ***Ion Gaztanaga*** (www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/interprocess/detail/robust_emulation.hpp)

He had nice idea how resolve abandoning state check. Each process in game has its own lock file and while is alive it hold that file locked. Then Ion's robust_mutex check, in case of failed lock attempt, current owner process lock file, and can determine if current mutex owner is alive or not. In case it is death mutex can be taken. Trick with file lock is nice idea cause file locks are unlocked by OS in case process die, and this seems to be well portable. This solution wraps base spin_mutex and hold current owner process id in internal field. I made intensive testing and found 2 big problems.

1. File lock handling and way how is implemented slows down mutex in manner that it is faster just use file lock.
2. Decoupling effective lock gate variable and owner process id cause situations where mutex can be stolen by different processes.

And here come my question : I'm proposing solution for both problems, and I wood like to have some pro opinion about it.

1. do not use for each existing process separate lock file but to use one file for all eventual process id (there should be enough 4MB) and for each process lock just one byte. Position of that byte is determined by process id itself. (this is not my idea but I found it in code of [Howard Chu and his excellent LMDB](http://symas.com/mdb/))
2. do not wrap spin_mutex as is, but rewrite it's code so it use as lock gate current owner process id instead just 0/1,  so lock and unlock can happen in one atomic CAS operation.

I did a try to implement it and tested on windows. I use original boost code and call boost where necessary. [Here is code](ftp://ftp.3di.it/3di/robust_mutex.zip). It's taken from our projects tree, so if you want to test it you have to adapt some include maybe. It's proposal, so please do not blame me for code style or something else. If idea and mode is good, I'll continue to make it more perfect. If not I'll just use something else, but I can't find anything else.

There are also versions for recursive_mutex, and named_mutex too. Then there is sort of 
fixing proposal, cause if one process take in owner ship precedentaly abandoned mutex, there is high probability that there must be done some sort of integrity check.

I'd like to discuss eventual improvements

Thank you in advance

Ladislav.

Comment: SO is not really the good place to discuss this. Why don't you ask this to the boost mailing lists ?

Comment: Nice Idea but this post is best suited on codereview.com

Comment: I'll do posts also to both suggested destinations, thx.

Comment: See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57083/portable-c-boostinterprocessmutex for one of the cross posts.